# C# - É possível colocar uma Scrollbar dentro de um Menustrip através do código, sem mexer no design?

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, rolamento

Olá!

Estou utilizando o Windows Forms e criei um menu com muitos items:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para poder visualizar todos os itens tenho que utilizar essas flechas que estão nas extremidades do menu. Queria poder adicionar uma Scrollbar ou algo do tipo para visualizar os itens com mais facilidade.

Não sei se é possível fazer isso diretamente pelo código, mas se alguém souber, agradeço.

Comment: não seria o caso de criar sub-itens ?

Comment: Não sei se tem como fazer o que pede, mas por questão de usabilidade, esta bem confuso esse menu, sugiro agrupa-los, por uma ou mais das seguintes formas, categoria, função, uso, etc. Se possível ainda, separa por mais menus.

Comment: Tem uma resposta no SOen, com esse tema, olhe: [Mouse wheel scrolling Toolstrip menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139074/mouse-wheel-scrolling-toolstrip-menu-items)

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou tentar reajustar o menu. Realmente seria melhor pra mim conseguir deixar ele dessa forma, mas caso não tenha jeito, farei isso.

Comment: Veja se [isso](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?430411-C-Menu-Strip-Scrolls-Out-Of-Sight) te ajuda.

Comment: Para ter um Scroll mesmo, acredito que só utilizando um outro Form